# BSInput of type Select is not firing on a change using Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

So in my page I have:

```
<BSInput InputType="InputType.Select" @bind-Value="_defaultVendorID">

     <option value=0>Please select default vendor</option>
     @foreach (var vendor in _viewModel.registration.Vendors)
     {
         <option value="@vendor.Id">@vendor.VendorName</option>
     }
 </BSInput>
```

and in my code behind I have:

```
private int _defaultVendorId = 0;
public int _defaultVendorID
{
    get => _defaultVendorId; 
    set 
    {
        _defaultVendorId = value;
        defaultVendor = (from v in _viewModel.registration.Vendors where _viewModel.registration.VendorId == _defaultVendorId select v).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

After my form has rendered I can see in the page I correctly have :
[image]

When I change the selection, my Setter does not get triggered. Can anybody suggest what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you have @bind-Value="_defaultVendorID", but in your code-behind, the property is named _defaultVendorId with a lowercase 'd'.

Update your HTML code:

```
<BSInput InputType="InputType.Select" @bind-Value="_defaultVendorId">
<option value=0>Please select default vendor</option>
@foreach (var vendor in _viewModel.registration.Vendors)
{
    <option value="@vendor.Id">@vendor.VendorName</option>
}
```

Or match it like this:

```
private int _defaultVendorID = 0;
public int _defaultVendorID
{
    get => _defaultVendorID; 
    set 
    {
        _defaultVendorID = value;
        defaultVendor = (from v in _viewModel.registration.Vendors where _viewModel.registration.VendorId == _defaultVendorID select v).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes my '_defaultVendorID' is the Get/set property whilst the '_defaultVendorId' is the Internal value.  We cannot declare a public and private variable by the same name '_defaultVendorID'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with BSInput, but if it uses standard bind techniques, why don't you just do something like this.  You have a standard bind and get the default vendor when you need to consume it.

```cs
private int _defaultVendorId = 0;
private Vendor _defaultVendor => (from v in _viewModel.registration.Vendors where _viewModel.registration.VendorId == _defaultVendorId select v).FirstOrDefault();
```

### Update

Here's a quick Demo using a `select` and `InputSelect`.  I can't believe that `BSInput` is any different.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<select class="form-select mb-3" @bind="_countryId">
    @if(_countryId == 0)
    {
        <option selected disabled value="0"> -- Select a Country -- </option>
    }
    @foreach(var country in _countries)
    {
        <option value="@country.CountryId">@country.CountryName</option>
    }

</select>

<InputSelect TValue="int" class="form-select mb-3" @bind-Value="_countryId">
    @if (_countryId == 0)
    {
        <option selected disabled value="0"> -- Select a Country -- </option>
    }
    @foreach (var country in _countries)
    {
        <option value="@country.CountryId">@country.CountryName</option>
    }

</InputSelect>


<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Country: @_selectedCountry</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private int _countryId;
    
    private string? _selectedCountry => _countries.SingleOrDefault(item => item.CountryId == _countryId)?.CountryName;


    public record Country (int CountryId, string? CountryName);

    public IEnumerable<Country> _countries = new List<Country>
    {
        new(1, "Portugal"),
        new(2, "France"),
        new(3, "Spain"),
        new(4, "UK"),
    };
}
```

Comment: I need to display the value somewhere else on the page when the user has selected a value, so I need to set it when the value changes in the dropdown and so it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: It will work either way.  The `EventCallback` from the Input control will mutate  `_defaultVendorId` and then when the page renders _defaultVendor  will get the correct entry from the Collection.

Comment: That's the problem, it doesn't call back

Comment: See my quick demo.  As I say, I can't see that `BSInput` handles binding any differently to every other version of select.